# Python emoji search and replace not working as expected

Tags: python, regex, string, emoji

I am trying to separate emoji in given text from other characters/words/emojis. I want to use emoji later as features in text classification. So it is important that I treat each emoji in the sentence individually and as a separate character.

The code:

```
import re

text = "I am very #happy man but my wife is not "
print(text) #line a

reg = re.compile(u'['
    u'\U0001F300-\U0001F64F'
    u'\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF'
    u'\u2600-\u26FF\u2700-\u27BF]+', 
    re.UNICODE)

#padding the emoji with space at both the ends
new_text = reg.sub(' \1 ',text) 
print(new_text) #line b

# this is just to test if it can still identify the emoji in new_text
new_text2 = reg.sub('#\1#', new_text) 
print(new_text2) # line c
```

Here is the actual output:

[image]

(I had to paste the screenshot because copy pasting the output here from terminal was distorting those already distorted emojis in line b and c)

Here is my expected output:

```
I am very #happy man but my wife is not 
I am very #happy man but     my wife   is not     
I am very #happy man but ##  ##  my wife ##  is not  ##  ##
```

Questions:

1) Why the search and replace is not working as expected? What is the emoji being replaced with? (line b). It is definitely not the unicode for the original emoji otherwise line c would have printed the emoji with # padded at the both ends.

2) I am not sure if I am right about this but - Why are the grouped emoji being replaced with a single emoji/unicode? (line b)

Comment: Do you expect this - http://rextester.com/UXJ28002 ? I see your expected output differs from what I get after fixing the most obvious issues.

Comment: I am expecting each emoji separated. See my second question and 3rd line in the expected output. Not sure why the grouped emoji aren't getting separated.

Comment: I think that happens because you quantified the character class, see http://rextester.com/RXOBH48259. Now, it looks like your expected output.

Comment: That seems to work. Can you please add it as an answer and explain in short where I went wrong? I am not great at python/regex yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues here.

- There is no capturing groups in the regex pattern, but in the replacement pattern, you define `\1` backreference  to Group 1 - so, the most natural workaround is to use a backreference to Group 0, i.e. the whole match, that is `\g<0>`.
- The `\1` in the replacement is not actually parsed as a backreference, but as a a char with an octal value 1 because the backslash in the regular (not raw) string literals forms *escape sequences*. Here, it is an octal escape.
- The `+` after the `]` means that the regex engine must match 1 or more occurrences of text matching the character class, so you match *sequences* of emojis rather than each separate emoji.

Use

```
import re

text = "I am very #happy man but my wife is not "
print(text) #line a

reg = re.compile(u'['
    u'\U0001F300-\U0001F64F'
    u'\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF'
    u'\u2600-\u26FF\u2700-\u27BF]', 
    re.UNICODE)

#padding the emoji with space at both ends
new_text = reg.sub(r' \g<0> ',text) 
print(new_text) #line b

# this is just to test if it can still identify the emojis in new_text
new_text2 = reg.sub(r'#\g<0>#', new_text) 
print(new_text2) # line c
```

See the [Python demo](http://rextester.com/UXJ28002) printing

```
I am very #happy man but my wife is not 
I am very #happy man but     my wife   is not     
I am very #happy man but ##  ##  my wife ##  is not  ##  ##
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Learnt something new.

Comment: Lots of people prefer readability to effciency, so you may also wrap the whole pattern with `(` and `)` and then use your `\1`, but always use *raw string literal*, that is, `r" \1 "`.

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks again. Regex are complicated. I don't know if I'll ever master them. :)